# How to disable LDAP account and keep access to Mail exchange in PHP?

Tags: php, powershell, ldap, windows-server

I'm Working on project that restricts employee access to windows account, I'm able to disable and enable LDAP account using this code:

```
$sr = ldap_search($ds, $ldapBase, "(samaccountname=$username)");
$ent= ldap_get_entries($ds,$sr);
$dn=$ent[0]["dn"];
$ac = $ent[0]["useraccountcontrol"][0];
$disable=($ac |  2); // set all bits plus bit 1 (=dec2)
$enable =($ac & ~2); // set all bits minus bit 1 (=dec2)
if ($enable_s==1) $new=$enable; else $new=$disable; //enable or disable?
$userdata["useraccountcontrol"][0]=$new;
ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $userdata);
```

But in this case the user will not be able to access his Mail account.

I want to allow user to log on to specific workstation in php (in my case exchange-mail), the same steps mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/998cca5b-544f-4e3e-b800-4090f7253800/how-to-restrict-a-computer-to-specific-user-login-?forum=winserverDS) using GUI.

Comment: Using Exchange Server you must have an enabled user account with the mailbox to login...

Comment: You mean the AD user should have two different accounts? so I can disable the AD User and keeps the other one (exchange-account) ?

Comment: no, I mean that Exchange mailbox must have an enabled user account, if you disable the user the mailbox will not work

Comment: I'm not sure but regard to company sys-admin If I restrict user access to specific workstation / computer name (which is exchange), that will deny the AD user from access his windows account but still can access his mailbox